# difference between strlen(string) and strlen( *string)

Tags: c, string, pointers

Let's say I have an array of strings that are all of same size.

```
char strings[][MAX_LENGTH];
```

what would be the difference between `strlen(strings)` and `strlen(*strings)`?

I know that `strings` by itself would be the address of the first string in the array,

but what is `*strings`?

Comment: You can't use `strlen(strings)` there. You should not do it at least, and a decent compiler would complain about that with a warning such as *incompatible type passed as the first parameter to `strlen()`*.

Comment: The answer you will find in any C book or tutorial about arrays in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't do this.  C will allow you to do lots of things that are a bad idea.  This doesn't mean you ought to do it. :)

While you may have compiler warnings, these two are effectively identical.  The reason is that with this definition:

```
char strings[][MAX_LENGTH];
```

The allocation for this will end up being one continuous block.  Within that block of memory, there are no "structures" or management devices that can be used to identify where individual strings start and stop.  This creates an interesting situation.

Effectively, `*string` and `string` are both pointers to precisely the same memory location.  This means that calling `strlen` on either one of them will return the null delimited string length of the first element in the first array.

However, I must reiterate... **Don't do this.**